# How To Display Bootstrap Toggle Switch with DataTables via Render

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datatables, toggle

I am using [Bootstrap Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/), CSS, and JavaScript loads fine please see image.However when I use inside datatable (Done coloumn) custom JavaScript and styling doesn't work.I am getting data via Ajax

Datatable Script

```
$('#sampleTable').DataTable( {
      "ajax": {
        "url": "/generalTodo",
        "dataSrc": ""
      },    
"columns": [
            {
             "sortable": true,
             className: 'centerize',
             render: function ( data, type, full, meta ) {

                return '<input type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">';


             }
            },.....
```

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
return '<input id="toggle-demo" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">';
```

and

```
"fnDrawCallback": function() {
            $('#toggle-demo').bootstrapToggle();
        },
```

Loading Js after table finish the loading!

Answer (score 0):

if you going to use loop add class

class="my_switch"

```
return '<input id="toggle-demo" class="my_switch" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-on="Ready" data-off="Not Ready" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">';
```

End on fnDrawCallback

```
"fnDrawCallback": function() {
   $('.my_switch').bootstrapToggle();
},
```